# FileSystemWatcher not working for existing files in a directory

Tags: c#, .net

I have written code for watching a file & whenever changes is made fire the event notifying user of changes. However it doesn't fire for the files already in a directory but in the same directory if I create a new file and make changes to it, works like a charm.

How to make it work for the files already existing in a particular directory?

```
private static void Watcher()
{
 using(FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path,filter))
 {
  watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;
  watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

  Console.ReadKey();
 }
}

private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
  {
    return;
  }
  Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: See example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0). There are different events you can subscribe to.

Comment: What event do you want to fire?

Comment: I have added the code which I used & its working fine for the new file(e.g .txt file) created. In the same directory there are lot of existing .txt file & when I edit and save it, no event(change event) is fired.

Comment: FSW works for existing files. If it didn't it would be useless. Once you create a new file it becomes an *existing* one when you try to change it. `LastAccess` is the last read time, not the last modification time. Try removing `NotifyFilter` entirely, and only filter when you really need it. The default  is `LastWrite | DirectoryName | FileName` and will catch modifications and renames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related with file extension which shows as "text document" in explorer window and when I checked in propertied its ".LOG". Modifying in the filter property fixed it.